# Camel filter method signatures

Tags: java, apache-camel, esb, middleware

I have an `Order` POJO, and on my Camel route I'd like to pass each `Order` instance (message) through a filter like so:

```
ExpensiveOrderFilter eof = new ExpensiveOrderFilter();

from("direct:whatever")
    .filter().method(eof)
    .to("direct:wherever");
```

The filter should only let `Order`s though if their `Order#getPrice()` is more than $100.00.

```
public class ExpensiveOrderFilter {
    public void filterCheapOrders(Order order) {
        if(order.getPrice() < 100.00)
            ???
        else
            ???
    }
}
```

What does the `filterCheapOrders` method need to look like so that it correctly filters out "cheap" (< $100) orders, preventing them from being routed on to `direct:wherever`? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two parts to this. The first is that `method(..)` is a type of Camel [expression](https://camel.apache.org/expression) called a predicate. Any actual method that you this will invoke needs to return a boolean, so:

```
public class ExpensiveOrderFilter {
    public boolean isCheapOrder(Order order) {
        return order.getPrice() < 100.00;
    }
}
```

The Order parameter will be injected in a best-attempt by a Camel mechanism called called [bean binding](https://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html), which will try to convert the body of the message to an Order. If it fails, the route will throw an exception.

You name the method that is to be invoked on the bean within the `method(..)` block:

```
.filter().method(eof, "isCheapOrder")
```

Only cheap orders will continue. For straightforward expressions you might also consider the [simple](https://camel.apache.org/simple.html) expression language built into Camel, and skip writing your bean:

```
.filter().simple("${body.price} < 100")
```

Comment: Where do you pass the `Order order` argument to the `isCheapOrder(Order order)` method? Is that "eof"?

Comment: eof is just an instance of ExpensiveOrderFilter. Camel will use bean binding (http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html) to pass the payload of the Exchange (the Order POJO) into the order argument.